# Laravel Migration Postgres error SQLSTATE[08006]

Tags: php, database, postgresql, laravel-5.5, pgadmin-4

I want to connect Laravel with Postgresql database

when I run

```
php artisan migrate
```

I get this error

> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] timeout expired (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = public and table_name = migrations)

my .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=projects.cggts***.rds.amazonaws.com
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=projects
DB_USERNAME=*********
DB_PASSWORD=*********
```

Comment: Check and see if the connection is there. And if the provided information in .env are responding. It may be a misconfig.

Answer (score 2):

It'll probably inbound VPC problem on AWS . You have to update IP range for your RDS db. You'll find it under ***EC2->Network & Security->Security Groups*** . Have fun ;)

Comment: Yeah it was related to inbound rules , thanks (Y)